# Insinkerator Hot Water Heater vent problem

Tags: water-heater, kitchen-sink

The vent tube on my white (latest model?) Insinkerator keeps detaching (blowing off under pressure?) causing leakage inside the cabinet.  Is the problem likely to lie in the faucet/tap or the heater itself.  Would it be safe to clamp the 1/8" tube to the heater to prevent it detaching itself from the top of the Heater?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no pressure in a vent tube. so it should not blow off.

Find and correct the blockage in the vent path.